# Write to CR2 during PageFault ISR

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, kernel, x86-64

I'm writing a pagefault handler, and I'm wondering what happens if the ISR changes the value of `cr2` right before the ISR returns.

For example, if some code does this:

```
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x23]
mov    rbx,QWORD PTR [rax+0x28432] 
movabs rax,0xdeadbeefdeadbeef
mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rax]
```

Let's say `[rax+0x28432]` has the `Present` bit in the `PTE` set to `0`. Let's also assume that the `0xdeadbeefdeadbeef` points to valid, but paged-out memory.

Assuming the code is the ISR (This is pseudocode):

```
PPTE pte = GetPteFromVA(__readcr2() & ~0xFFF);

/* Bring page into memory */

pte->Present = 1;

__writecr2(newValue);
__asm
{
    add rsp, 8
    iretq
}
```

What will happen back in the code? Will the instruction that loads `rbx` with a value use the updated `cr2` value in its computation? What will happen when trying to load `rcx` with the value that `rax` is pointing to? Is `cr2` only used for notifying the kernel of a faulting address? Or will something break?

Comment: 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef is, of course, a non canonical address, so it will cause #GP, but that will happen only after the first page fault is resolved and the load into rbx is completed. Assuming you change 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef to a canonical address, you'll get a second page fault on the load of rcx, completely unrelated to the page fault on the load of rbx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the page fault handler returns, the faulting instruction is reexecuted. Assuming the fault handler preserves all register values, as it must, when the instruction is reexecuted it will attempt to access the same address again. CR2 isn't used.

A page fault on a subsequent instruction can happen only after the first page fault is resolved and the memory access is completed. Assuming you change 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef to a canonical address, you'll get a second page fault on the load of rcx, completely unrelated to the page fault on the load of rbx.